# Passing Credential to SockJs+Stompjs on CORS

Tags: sockjs, spring-websocket

i have  application connected to websocket server

i am using spring websocket which secured by spring security

```
e.g "http://192.168.3.88:8080/api/websocket"
```

> api/** is secured by spring security

so how to pas credentials from login to SockJS?
because sockJs read this as an Authorized url

```
socket.client = new SockJS("http://192.168.3.88:8080/api/websocket")
socket.stomp = Stomp.over(socket.client) // this is unauthorized
socket.stomp.connect {}, startListener
```

here my spring cors config :

> String origin = request.getHeader(ORIGIN);
>
> ```
>     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
>
>     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
>
>     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
>
>     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "origin, content-type, accept, authorization, x-requested-with");
>
>     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
>
>     if (request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
>         try {
>             response.getWriter().print("OK");
>             response.getWriter().flush();
>         } catch (IOException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     } else {
>         chain.doFilter(req, res);
>     }
> ```

Comment: I have the same issue, `Cookie` is not set in the request header. Did you find any solution? I'm looking for one.

Comment: if u are using spring security the websocket will automatically pass when u are logged.. so dont worried about credential..